# how to marge and sort an array in follow rule

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

i have a problem. i need to do a function that received 2 arrays in size n, m. and return a new array with common numbers inside in min length. 
 example:

```
      A: 2 5 3 1 2 4 6 2 4 3 5 2

      B: 7 5 2 5 8 1 2 5 9 2
```

and new array gonna look like:

```
      C:  1 2 2 2 5 5
```

and the size of new array must be 6.

here what i did so far. (but its don't work, and i cant find the problem)

```
 int *same_same(int *ar1, int *ar2,int n, int m)
{
    int *c; 
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int min=n;
    if (n>m)
        min=m;
    c=(int *)calloc(min, sizeof(int)); 
    bubble_sort (ar1, n);
    bubble_sort (ar2, m);

while( i<n  &&  j<m ) 
{ 
    if (ar1[i] == ar2[j])
    {
        c[k++]=ar1[i++];
        j++;

    }
    else if (ar1[i] < ar2[j])
        i++;
    else j++;

} 
c=(int *)realloc(k, sizeof(int));
return c;
free (c);
}
```

**The full code is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
int *input_array_dyn(int n)
{ 
    int i;  
    int *a; 
    a=(int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int)); 
    assert(a);   
    printf("enter the array of length %d\n",n); 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)   
        scanf_s("%lf",a+i); 
    return a; 
} 
void swap(int *v,int *u)  //function aid for ex3
{ 
    int temp;  
    temp=*v; 
    *v=*u; 
    *u=temp;  
}   
void bubble_sort(int *a, int n)
{  
    int i,j;   
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++) 
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)  
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])    
                swap(&a[j],&a[j+1]); 

}
 int *same_same(int *ar1, int *ar2,int n, int m)
{
    int *c; 
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int min=n;
    if (n>m)
        min=m;
    c=(int *)calloc(min, sizeof(int)); 
    bubble_sort (ar1, n);
    bubble_sort (ar2, m);

while( i<n  &&  j<m ) 
{ 
    if (ar1[i] == ar2[j])
    {
        c[k++]=ar1[i++];
        j++;

    }
    else if (ar1[i] < ar2[j])
        i++;
    else j++;

} 
c=(int *)realloc(k, sizeof(int));
return c;
free (c);
}
int main(void)
{
    int  *arr1 , *arr2 ,n,m; // input for Ex 3
    printf_s("Please Insert Size of array one :\n");
                scanf_s("%d",&n);
                printf_s("Please Insert Size of array two :\n");
                scanf_s("%d",&m);
                printf_s("Please Insert numbers of array one :\n");
                arr1=input_array_dyn(n);
                printf_s("Please Insert numbers of array two :\n");
                arr2=input_array_dyn(m);
                printf_s("The new array is :\n");
                same_same(arr1,arr2,n,m);
                free (arr1);
                free (arr2);
```

}

Comment: There are six `2`'s between the two original arrays.  What is the logic by which only three `2`'s appear in the output array?

Comment: number 2 showing 4 time in array A. and just 3 times in array B . and in array C it will be shown just 3 time because its repeat 3 time in array B. l'ts say if the number 0 was repeat 5 times in array and just 3 times in array B . the new array C will be just 3 time number 0

Comment: 1) `c=(int *)realloc(k, sizeof(int));` --> `c=realloc(c, k*sizeof(int));`

Comment: 2) `scanf_s("%lf",a+i);` --> `scanf_s("%d", a+i);`

Comment: 3) `same_same` doesn't display result and doesn't  `free`d `c`.

Comment: still not working... do you have maybe some offer how i fix the code ?

Comment: Describe the details of "not working". It seems to [work](http://ideone.com/ymn7PU).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version with fixes. Calling realloc() does not guarantee that the returned pointer will be at the same place. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/
"Return Value. A pointer to the reallocated memory block, which may be either the same as ptr or a new location."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(int *v,int *u)  //function aid for ex3
{ 
    int temp;  
    temp=*v; 
    *v=*u; 
    *u=temp;  
} 

void bubble_sort(int *a, int n)
{  
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])    
                swap(&a[j],&a[j+1]);

}

void *same_same(int *ar1, int *ar2,int n, int m, int ** res, int * res_size)
{
    int *c; 
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int min=n;
    if (n>m)
        min=m;
    c=(int *)calloc(min, sizeof(int)); 
    bubble_sort (ar1, n);
    bubble_sort (ar2, m);

    while( i<n  &&  j<m ) 
    { 
        if (ar1[i] == ar2[j])
        {
            c[k++]=ar1[i++];
            j++;

        }
        else if (ar1[i] < ar2[j]){
            i++;}
        else j++;

    }

    // Fixes
    *res_size = k;
    (*res) = (int *) calloc(*res_size, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(*res, c, (*res_size)*sizeof(int));
    free(c);
}

//Example code
int main(void)
{
    int  arr1[] =  {2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2};
    int  arr2[] = {7, 5, 2, 5, 8, 1, 2, 5, 9, 2}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int);
    int m = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int);
    // input for Ex 3
    int *res;
    int res_size;
    same_same(arr1,arr2,n,m, &res, &res_size);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < res_size; i++)
        printf("%d ", res[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and how i can do the same but without get another 2 arrays?  i need the function same_same input will be just (arr1, arr2 ,n ,m)                                        when n=size of arr1 . m= size of arr2

Comment: Use local variable, say int * d, and use it the same way as *res in same_same() function ( return d at the end). However, in this case you wont know the size of the array.